# Сбой при установке MS SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server

При установке служб ядра СУБД возникает сбой.
Скриншоты процесса установки и лог приведены ниже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
Overall summary:
  Final result:                  Ошибка: дополнительные сведения см. ниже
  Exit code (Decimal):           -2068054016
  Start time:                    2017-07-21 21:36:09
  End time:                      2017-07-21 21:42:19
  Requested action:              Install

Setup completed with required actions for features.
Troubleshooting information for those features:
  Next step for SQLEngine:       Устраните ошибку, пользуясь следующими сведениями, а затем запустите процесс установки еще раз.


Machine Properties:
  Machine name:                  
  Machine processor count:       4
  OS version:                    Майкрософт Windows 8.1 Корпоративная (6.3.9600)
  OS service pack:               
  OS region:                     Россия
  OS language:                   русский (Россия)
  OS architecture:               x64
  Process architecture:          64-разрядная версия
  OS clustered:                  Нет

Product features discovered:
  Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered  Configured
  SQL Server 2016                                                          SSMS                                     1033                                      13.0.15600.2    Нет        Да        
  SQL Server 2016                                                          Adv_SSMS                                 1033                                      13.0.15600.2    Нет        Да        

Package properties:
  Description:                   Microsoft SQL Server 2016 
  ProductName:                   SQL Server 2016
  Type:                          RTM
  Version:                       13
  Installation location:         C:\SQLServer2016Media\Developer\x64\setup\
  Installation edition:          Developer

  Slipstream:                    True
  SP Level                       1

Product Update Status:
  Успешно: KB 3182545

Product Updates Selected for Installation:
  Title:                         Microsoft SQL Server 2016  with SP1
  Knowledge Based Article:       KB 3182545
  Version:                       13.1.4001.0
  Architecture:                  x64
  Language:                      1049

  Update Source:                 Slipstream


Параметры пользовательского ввода:
  ACTION:                        Install
  ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN:      false
  AGTSVCACCOUNT:                 NT Service\SQLAgent$DF_FM
  AGTSVCPASSWORD:                *****
  AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Manual
  ASBACKUPDIR:                   Backup
  ASCOLLATION:                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
  ASCONFIGDIR:                   Config
  ASDATADIR:                     Data
  ASLOGDIR:                      Log
  ASPROVIDERMSOLAP:              1
  ASSERVERMODE:                  MULTIDIMENSIONAL
  ASSVCACCOUNT:                  <не заполнено>
  ASSVCPASSWORD:                 <не заполнено>
  ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS:            <не заполнено>
  ASTELSVCACCT:                  <не заполнено>
  ASTELSVCPASSWORD:              <не заполнено>
  ASTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
  ASTEMPDIR:                     Temp
  BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:         Disabled
  CLTCTLRNAME:                   <не заполнено>
  CLTRESULTDIR:                  <не заполнено>
  CLTSTARTUPTYPE:                0
  CLTSVCACCOUNT:                 <не заполнено>
  CLTSVCPASSWORD:                <не заполнено>
  CLTWORKINGDIR:                 <не заполнено>
  COMMFABRICENCRYPTION:          0
  COMMFABRICNETWORKLEVEL:        0
  COMMFABRICPORT:                0
  CONFIGURATIONFILE:             C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20170721_213608\ConfigurationFile.ini
  CTLRSTARTUPTYPE:               0
  CTLRSVCACCOUNT:                <не заполнено>
  CTLRSVCPASSWORD:               <не заполнено>
  CTLRUSERS:                     <не заполнено>
  ENABLERANU:                    false
  ENU:                           false
  EXTSVCACCOUNT:                 <не заполнено>
  EXTSVCPASSWORD:                <не заполнено>
  FEATURES:                      SQLENGINE
  FILESTREAMLEVEL:               0
  FILESTREAMSHARENAME:           <не заполнено>
  FTSVCACCOUNT:                  <не заполнено>
  FTSVCPASSWORD:                 <не заполнено>
  HELP:                          false
  IACCEPTROPENLICENSETERMS:      false
  IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS:  true
  INDICATEPROGRESS:              false
  INSTALLSHAREDDIR:              C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR:           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSQLDATADIR:             <не заполнено>
  INSTANCEDIR:                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\DF_FM
  INSTANCEID:                    DF_FM
  INSTANCENAME:                  DF_FM
  ISSVCACCOUNT:                  NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
  ISSVCPASSWORD:                 <не заполнено>
  ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  ISTELSVCACCT:                  <не заполнено>
  ISTELSVCPASSWORD:              <не заполнено>
  ISTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
  MATRIXCMBRICKCOMMPORT:         0
  MATRIXCMSERVERNAME:            <не заполнено>
  MATRIXNAME:                    <не заполнено>
  MRCACHEDIRECTORY:              
  NPENABLED:                     0
  PBDMSSVCACCOUNT:               <не заполнено>
  PBDMSSVCPASSWORD:              <не заполнено>
  PBDMSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
  PBENGSVCACCOUNT:               <не заполнено>
  PBENGSVCPASSWORD:              <не заполнено>
  PBENGSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
  PBPORTRANGE:                   <не заполнено>
  PBSCALEOUT:                    false
  PID:                           *****
  QUIET:                         false
  QUIETSIMPLE:                   false
  ROLE:                          
  RSINSTALLMODE:                 DefaultNativeMode
  RSSHPINSTALLMODE:              DefaultSharePointMode
  RSSVCACCOUNT:                  <не заполнено>
  RSSVCPASSWORD:                 <не заполнено>
  RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  SAPWD:                         <не заполнено>
  SECURITYMODE:                  <не заполнено>
  SQLBACKUPDIR:                  <не заполнено>
  SQLCOLLATION:                  Cyrillic_General_CI_AS
  SQLSVCACCOUNT:                 NT Service\MSSQL$DF_FM
  SQLSVCINSTANTFILEINIT:         false
  SQLSVCPASSWORD:                <не заполнено>
  SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Automatic
  SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS:           
  SQLTELSVCACCT:                 NT Service\SQLTELEMETRY$DF_FM
  SQLTELSVCPASSWORD:             <не заполнено>
  SQLTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:          Automatic
  SQLTEMPDBDIR:                  <не заполнено>
  SQLTEMPDBFILECOUNT:            4
  SQLTEMPDBFILEGROWTH:           64
  SQLTEMPDBFILESIZE:             8
  SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR:               <не заполнено>
  SQLTEMPDBLOGFILEGROWTH:        64
  SQLTEMPDBLOGFILESIZE:          8
  SQLUSERDBDIR:                  <не заполнено>
  SQLUSERDBLOGDIR:               <не заполнено>
  SUPPRESSPRIVACYSTATEMENTNOTICE: false
  TCPENABLED:                    0
  UIMODE:                        Normal
  UpdateEnabled:                 true
  UpdateSource:                  Slipstream
  USEMICROSOFTUPDATE:            false
  X86:                           false

  Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20170721_213608\ConfigurationFile.ini

Detailed results:
  Feature:                       Службы ядра СУБД
  Status:                        Ошибка. Дополнительные сведения см. в журнале.
  Reason for failure:            Возникла ошибка для одной из зависимостей компонента, вызвавшая сбой процесса его установки.
  Next Step:                     Устраните ошибку, пользуясь следующими сведениями, а затем запустите процесс установки еще раз.
  Component error code:          0
  Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20170721_213608\dacfx_Cpu32_1.log
  Error description:             A newer version of Microsoft SQL Server Data-Tier Application Framework is already installed.
  Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=13.0.4001.0&EvtType=DACFramework.msi%40LaunchConditions%400

Rules with failures:

Global rules:

Scenario specific rules:

Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20170721_213608\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm
```

Answer (score 2):

Вероятно, у Вас установлена Visual Sudio 2017.

1. Зайдите в **Установку и удаление программ**.
2. Найдите **Microsoft SQL Server Data-Tier Application Framework** и удалите его.
3. Запустите установку SQL Server заново - она должна пройти успешно. В ходе установки компонент снова появится в списке установленных программ.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. В моём случае поставилось с Visual Sudio 2015